# Did Euler discover the Euler's identity

Tags: complex-numbers, math-history

We know that in $1748$ Euler published the "Introductio  in analysin infinitorum", in which, he released the discovery of the Euler's formula:

$$e^{ix} = \cos x+i \sin x$$

But who was the first mathematician to convert this to the form we all know and love, the Euler's identity:

$$e^{i\pi}+1=0$$
When was this formula first explicitly written in this way?

Was it Bernoulli, Euler's teacher and mentor, or another more modern mathematician?

Comment: Whoever chose $x=\pi$ (there was probably more than one person who thought it might be a good idea to give it a try and see what happens)...

Comment: See http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2007-08.pdf

Comment: This isn't an answer but for what it's worth I don't really think plugging $\pi$ into the identity constitutes much of a discovery, especially since the concept of mathematical beauty is so subjective.

Comment: **The [Arnold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Arnold) Principle:** If a notion bears a personal name, then this name is not the name of the discoverer. **The Berry Principle:** The Arnold Principle is applicable to itself.

Comment: @Barry Cipra I have already read this, hence why i'm asking, since Quote: " The name of the Euler identity presents a slightly different problem.  Though it is only a special case of the Euler formula, it seems that he never wrote it down.  I have made no progress in finding who was the first to do so"

Comment: Perhaps http://hsm.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: As a matter of personal athetics, $e^{\pi i} = -1$ is more pleasing to me than $e^{i\pi} +1 = 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a reference pointing to Euler, see :

- Leonhard Euler, [“De la controverse entre Mrs. Leibnitz & Bernoulli sur les logarithmes des nombres négatifs et imaginaires”](http://eulerarchive.maa.org//docs/originals/E168.pdf) (1751), page 147 (9),

discussing Bernoulli's thesis that $l (-1)=l(+1)=0$ :

> le rayon [du cercle] est à la quatrieme partie de la circonference, comme $\sqrt -1$ à $l \sqrt -1$. Donc posant le rapport du diametre à la circonference $= 1 : \pi$, il sera $\frac 1 2 \pi = \dfrac {l \sqrt -1}{\sqrt -1}$ et pertant $l \sqrt -1 = \frac 1 2 \pi \sqrt -1$.

In a nutshell, he derive for the area of the first quadrant of the unit circle the formula :

> $\dfrac {\pi} 4 = \dfrac 1 {4 \sqrt -1} l (-1)$,

from which : $l (-1) = \pi \sqrt -1$.

---

See also page 165-on where, starting from his formula "dont la vérité est suffissament prouvée ailleurs" :

> $$x= \text {cos} \phi + \sqrt -1 \ \text {sin} \phi \ ,$$

posing $C$ as the real logarithm of the positive quantity $\sqrt {(aa+bb)}=c$, he derives the general formula for the logarithm of :

> $$a+b \sqrt -1 = C + (\phi + p \pi) \sqrt -1.$$

With $c=1$ and $C=0$ he get :

> $$l (\text {cos} \phi + \sqrt -1 \ \text {sin} \phi) = (\phi + p \pi) \sqrt -1.$$

Finally, with $\phi = 0$ [and thus : $\text {cos} \phi = 1$ and $\text {sin} \phi = 0$] :

> $l(+1) = p \pi \sqrt (-1)$ and thus [for $p=0$] : $l(+1) = 0$

and, with $\phi = \pi$ :

> $l(-1) = \frac + - \pi \sqrt -1$.

---

Euler in : [Introductio in analysin infinitorum, Tomus Secundus (1748)](https://books.google.it/books?id=YHNdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA290), **Ch.XXI**, page 290, uses $i$ for an *imaginary quantity* :

> Cum enim numerorum negativorum Logarithmi sint imaginarii (...) erit $l(-n)$, quantitas imaginaria, quae sit $= i$.

But he does not say that the symbol $i$ is such that $i^2 = -1$.

In the same *Introductio*, Tomus Primus, [§138](https://books.google.it/books?id=_zpRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA104), the formula is written as :

> $e^{v \sqrt -1}= \text {cos} v + \sqrt -1 \text {sin} v$.

---

In conclusion, Euler "knows" the identity and he is the "iventor" of $i$ to name an imaginary quantity, but it seems that he never writed it in the "modern form", at least because he constantly writes $\sqrt -1$.

---

---

*Note*

See also Cuchy's [Cours (1821)](https://books.google.it/books?id=wAsOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA310) for Euler's identity ; again, $\sqrt -1$ is used.

I've not made an extensive research but, due to the fact that Cauchy uses systematically $i$ for denoting an *increment* [see : [Résumé des leçons sur le calcul infinitésimal (1823)](https://books.google.it/books?id=uN5UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA9) ] :

> $\Delta x = i$,

my conjecture is that we hardly find any use of $i$ as imaginary.

Comment: Can I ask for more detail please, or an English translation, I'm not sure just by looking at this what it means. I'm assuming that that from http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3804/eulers-identity-history this is a proof for the Euler's formula, but not the derivation of the Euler's Identity.

Comment: @UniStuffz - I've not "formally" asserted that Euler writed the so-called Euler's identity... but it seems quite clear the "link" : if we use $\text e$ on both sides what we get is : $-1=\text e ^{ \pi \sqrt -1}$.

Comment: Nice answer!  Could you clarify it by summarizing what you are arguing here?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Great, this answered my question, before I mark it as correct, just one more question. In your research did you find who was the first to write it in the "modern form". Or do you know where I can find the information.

Comment: @UniStuffz - no, sorry. Maybe Gauss ? But it is hard to check: so many pubblications...